# Method on unnamed struct type

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand what the below code block does;

```
var cache = struct {
sync.Mutex
mapping map[string]string
} {
mapping: make(map[string]string),
}
```

I don't understand the presence of `} {` or what the last line does.

Comment: The question title is misleading: There are no methods in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text

```
struct {
   sync.Mutex
   mapping map[string]string
} {
   mapping: make(map[string]string),
}
```

is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).  The [literal's type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#LiteralType) is the anonymous [struct type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#StructType):

```
struct {
   sync.Mutex
   mapping map[string]string
}
```

The [literal's value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#LiteralValue) is

```
{
   mapping: make(map[string]string),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down:

```
// create a variable cache of type anonymous struct
var cache = struct {
    // Define anonymous struct fields
    sync.Mutex
    mapping map[string]string
} { // Close struct definition; open value literal
    mapping: make(map[string]string), // specify a field in the value
} // Close value literal
```

Basically this statement defines a variable `cache`, specifies its type, and assigns it a value. The first set of braces encloses the type definition, the second set encloses the value literal. The variable's type is `struct { sync.Mutex, mapping map[string]string }`.